# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console unable to understand

Tags: visual-studio, logging, console, asp.net-core-mvc

I am confused why we have to  us this package.

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
```

I have 3 questions.
1. what is logging, whats the advantages of logging, and if i don't use it then whats pitfalls.?

2.what is logging.console, why we have to use it?

3.what is loggerfactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should always have a logging facility in your application, without log entries it will be hard to find runtime bugs as there will be no information on what is happening in your application. Its not required to use it, but in a production environment it is a must have thing.
2. Logging.Console configures the logging facility to print out the log entries in the console, there are others provider options and you can write a custom one as well.
3. The LoggerFactory is an abstraction that "behind the hood" redirects your log messages to all installed providers, so you can have as many log outputs as you want by only changing the application startup.

I recommend to read the asp net core [logging fundamentals documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging)

Comment: Its Really helpful thanks.
one thing more when i searching about this i read that it use to store log eateries in the log file so where is log file in our project?

Comment: Take a look in [file providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers), to store in a file you must use the FileProvider, so you can configure the filepath that stores the log entries